# Html5 canvas not drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a problem with an object not drawing it's image. I've set the onload property of the image to the draw function..

```
//ctor
function Sprite(someargs,pContext)
    this.setContext(pContext); //This could be the problem?
    this.setX(px); 
    this.setY(py);
    this.setTexture(pImagePath);    


//I run this in the constructor 
Sprite.prototype.setTexture = function(pImagePath){
    this.texture = new Image();
    this.texture.onload = this.draw();  
    this.texture.src = pImagePath;
};

Sprite.prototype.draw = function(){

    this.getContext().drawImage(this.texture,this.getX(),this.getY(),100,100);
};

Sprite.prototype.setContext = function(pContext){
       this.mContext = pContext;
};
```

No errors at runtime, image not drawn onto canvas though. 
I'v put alerts in all the above methods, all of which are being executed.

Anyone got any ideas as to why it's not drawing?

Cheers

Comment: I think you'll need to show how you're actually instantiating the context - no point saying "this might be where the problem is but I've removed the code" :)

Comment: Is setContext called before setTexture ?

Comment: Updated code, yeah I call setContext first

Comment: `function Sprite(someargs,context)  this.setContext(pContext);` // your argument is called `context` but you use `pContext` later

Comment: Sorry forgot to alter that in my edit. The code syntax is all valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.texture.onload = this.draw();
```

you are not setting `onload` to the `draw` function but to the **result** of `draw` function

```
this.texture.onload = this.draw;
```

also wouldn't be good because you will lose your context of `this` in here.
`this` inside of `draw` function will point to `texture` instead of `Sprite`

you need to `bind` the function `draw` to `this` (which is the `Sprite` at the moment) and pass it to `onload`

```
this.texture.onload = this.draw.bind(this);
```

or:

```
var that = this;
this.texture.onload = function() { that.draw(); }
```

Comment: Ah wicked that sorted it out. Thank you!